# How to solve following differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integral-equations

$$
\int \limits_{0}^{\infty}\sqrt{1 + y'^{2}(x)}dx = 2 \sqrt{x} + y \qquad (.1) 
$$
The solution is
$$
3y = x\sqrt{x} - 3\sqrt{x} .
$$
I don't know how to solve this type of equations. Also I don't understand how the right-hand side of the equation (.1) may depend on the variable x.

Can you help me?

[image: For the comment]

Comment: Yeah if you look carefully the left-hand side does not depend on x at all, so something is wrong here.

Comment: I agree with you, but I found four equations of this type in some list of problems (look at the changed body of the question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is something I don't understand here.

If $y$ is a solution of this equation, note that the lhs is a constant.

So
$$
y=-2\sqrt{x}+C.
$$

Now plugging this back into the integral yields $+\infty$.

So I find that there are no solutions.

Comment: Oh, maybe I made a mistake. You can see this equation (# 1420) in a screenshot located in the body of my question. Maybe the upper limit is x.

Comment: @Maxim_Ovchinnikov This is very strange... It looks like I would get to the same conclusion (no solutions) for each of them. Where did you find the so-called solution? In the same book?

Comment: I just solved our equation. Excuse me, I didn't see that the upper limit of the integral is x, not infinity.
Thank you!

Comment: @Maxim_Ovchinnikov If I read correctly, in 1420, the upper bound of the integral is $\infty$.

Comment: The answer for the x-limit I got is correct. But the limit is very similar to infinity. [:(].

Comment: @Maxim_Ovchinnikov I don't understand your last comment. What limit are you talking about?

Comment: An upper limit of integration in equation (.1) from the list. Excuse me for my bad English.

Comment: @Maxim_Ovchinnikov So you are saying that there is a typo and it should be $x$ the upper bound of the integral?

Comment: Yes, that is so.